# Why my VGPRs Usage increases so fast when I use this assignment statement code in OpenCL?

Tags: optimization, opencl

```
if (condition)
{
printf("find:%d\n",gid);
*foundFlag = 1;
dst[gid] = gid * crack_cnt + num;
break;
}
```

This code is used in ending kernel funtion when password is found.
*foundFlag is a pointer to a char value,defined in kernel funtion formal parameters as follows:

```
__global char * foundFlag，
```

when I Comment * foundFlag = 1，the usage of VGPRs by CodeXL，only use 4 VGPRs Registers：
[image: registers]

But when this line code running,the usage of VGPRs increase to 88 VGPRs Registers:
[image: registers2]
I guarantee that I just modified this line of code, and that foundFlag is only used here. I'm confused.If you can help me solve this problem I will be grateful.(0_0)

Comment: You have to have in mind that compilers are quite clever these days. And that commenting that line may lead to the compiler doing optimizations elsewhere that leads to a huge reduction of code or that improves the vectorization of the code.

Comment: @DarkZeros I don't think this applies here - there's other side effects within the conditional (`printf` and `dst[gid] = ...`) and it looks like `foundFlag` is being used exclusively as an output of the kernel. Unless there's another conditional operating on `foundFlag` later, I don't think that commenting it out would result in a significant optimization, although the only way to be sure is to check the compiled output I suppose.